# Scala: how to avoid passing the same object instance everywhere in the code

Tags: scala, design-patterns, dependency-injection

I have a complex project which reads configurations from a DB through the object `ConfigAccessor` which implements two basic APIs: `getConfig(name: String)` and `storeConfig(c: Config)`.

Due to how the project is currently designed, almost every component needs to use the `ConfigAccessor` to talk with the DB. Thus, being this component an object it is easy to just import it and call its static methods.

Now I am trying to build some unit tests for the project in which the configurations are stored in a in-memory hashMap. So, first of all I decoupled the config accessor logic from its storage (using the cake pattern). In this way I can define my own `ConfigDbComponent` while testing

```
class ConfigAccessor {
   this: ConfigDbComponent => 
   ...
```

The "problem" is that now `ConfigAccessor` is a class, which means I have to instantiate it at the beginning of my application and pass it everywhere to whoever needs it. The first way I can think of for passing this instance around would be through other components constructors. This would become quite verbose (adding a parameter to every constructor in the project).

What do you suggest me to do? Is there a way to use some design pattern to overcome this verbosity or some external mocking library would be more suitable for this?

Comment: The way you describe `ConfigAccessor` is a common behaviour, Instead of creating a class, try it with trait https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/traits.html and still use cake pattern

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the "right" way is passing it in constructors. You can reduce verbosity by providing a default argument:

```
class Foo(config: ConfigAccessor = ConfigAccessor) { ... }
```

There are some "dependency injection" frameworks, like guice or spring, built around this, but I won't go there, because I am not a fan.

You could also continue utilizing the cake pattern:

```
 trait Configuration {
    def config: ConfigAccessor
 }

 trait Foo { self: Configuration => ... }

 class FooProd extends Foo with ProConfig
 class FooTest extends Foo with TestConfig
```

Alternatively, use the "static setter". It minimizes changes to existing code, but requires mutable state, which is really frowned upon in scala:

```
object Config extends ConfigAccessor {
  @volatile private var accessor: ConfigAccessor = _

  def configurate(cfg: ConfigAccessor) = synchronized {
    val old = accessor
    accessor = cfg
    old
  }
  def getConfig(c: String) = Option(accessor).fold(
   throw new IllegalStateException("Not configurated!")
  )(_.getConfig(c))
```

Comment: I think I will use the last one, even though I would prefer avoiding mutable state but it seems the less verbose solution. Regarding using the cake pattern for all dependencies: `FooProd` is now a class, so it requires initialization and all its clients need to receive somehow the instantiated object, meaning that the verbosity problem is still there. What I would like to do is somehow still keeping `FooProd` an object so that every client can just import it.

Comment: You don't need that `var` in the last option, use a `lazy val = GetConfigAccessor()` instead. That way you avoid a potential race condition and don't need to check for validity. `GetConfigAccessor` can do a run-time check for the appropriate accessor, or can have different implementations in different builds.

Comment: your example uses a `var`; could you show me how to not use it there?

Comment: @Tim `lazy val` approach defeats the purpose of the whole thing, which is to use different configs in different environments. "Different implementations in different builds" is an interesting idea, but it would have to use meta-tools, like macros, code generation or reflection. My focus was to show possible solutions that only used resources intrinsic to the language.

Comment: @Dima I have added more detail to my answer, but unit test builds always have different code from the production builds so there is no problem putting `GetConfigAccessor` in with that code. No macros, reflection or any other stuff required.

Comment: @Tim unit test builds do not (well .. _should_ not) have different code. They can have _additional_ code, not included into the main build, but they should not have code, that alters production code behavior.

Answer (score -1):

You can retain a global `ConfigAccessor` and allow selectable accessors like this:

```
object ConfigAccessor {
  private lazy val accessor = GetConfigAccessor()

  def getConfig(name: String) = accessor.getConfig(name)
  ...
}
```

For production builds you can put logic in `GetConfigAccessor` to select the appropriate accessor based on some global config such as typesafe config.

For unit testing you can have a different version of `GetConfigAccessor` for different test builds which return the appropriate test implementation.

Making this value `lazy` allows you to control the order of initialisation and if necessary do some non-functional mutable stuff in the initialisation code before creating the components.

---

#### Update following comments

The production code would have an implementation of `GetConfigAccessor` something like this:

```
object GetConfigAccessor {
  private val useAws = System.getProperties.getProperty("accessor.aws") == "true"

  def apply(): ConfigAccessor =
    if (useAws) {
      return new AwsConfigAccessor
    } else {
      return new PostgresConfigAccessor
  }
}
```

Both `AwsConfigAccessor` and `PostgresConfigAccessor` would have their own unit tests to prove that they conform to the correct behaviour. The appropriate accessor can be selected at runtime by setting the appropriate system property.

For unit testing there would be a simpler implementation of `GetConfigAccessor`, something like this:

```
def GetConfigAccessor() = new MockConfigAccessor
```

Unit testing is done within a unit testing framework which contains a number of libraries and mock objects that are not part of the production code. These are built separately and are not compiled into the final product. So this version of `GetConfigAccessor` would be part of that unit testing code and would not be part of the final product.

---

Having said all that, I would only use this model for **reading** static configuration data because that keeps the code functional. The `ConfigAccessor` is just a convenient way to access global constants without having them passed down in the constructor.

If you are also **writing** data then this is more like a real DB than a configuration.  In that case I would create custom accessors for each component that give access to different parts of the DB. That way it is clear which parts of the data are updated by each component. These accessors would be passed down to the component and can then be unit tested with the appropriate mock implementation as normal.

You may need to partition your data into *static config* and *dynamic config* and handle them separately.

Comment: this means that `GetConfigAccessor` would be an object in which I do something like `if (test) mockAccessor else dbAccessor`, which means that the testing logic should be included in the source code, am I correct?

Comment: @alexlipa For testing I would just have a test implementation of `GetConfigAccessor` that is linked into the test build to avoid it appearing in production code. The product code would have a different version that chose the accessor based on some static config like typesafe config.

Comment: so I should check some config to understand we are in testing mode, right?

Comment: @alexlipa yeah, you would have to check config ... which is exactly the thing you are trying to access here in the first place :) I don't think this is a viable solution. 
Checking an environment variable or an external resource for the name of implementation class, and then instantiating it using reflection might work. But that means adding a significant piece of untested and unsafe logic into your production code. I'd stick with `var`

Comment: @alexlipa I have added some more explanation to my answer. For testing it would be best to compile a different implementation of `GetConfigAccessor` rather than checking for testing code in the production build.

Comment: @Dima It is not helpful to give an incorrect answer to a question that was not directed at you in the first place.

Comment: @Tim I never give incorrect answers. You are mistaken.
Polluting production code with testing artifacts is an anti-pattern to be avoided.

Comment: @Dima Thanks for the downvote. I explained very clearly why you do not need to have the test code in the production build.

Comment: @Tim In your example, the whole `if (inMemory)` business _is_ the test code in production build (if you want to see it even more clearly, replace `InMemoryConfigAccessor` with `mock[ConfigAccessor]`). 
So, you may think you "explained" something, but your own example makes clear, that must realize, what you are "explaining" isn't really possible.

Comment: @Dima Ah, I can see why you are confused. I have changed the names to make it obvious that the production code is selecting between two different product implementations (AWS and Postgres) and there is no test code in the production version..

Comment: @Tim I am not confused. The question is about testing, not about product implementations. You are seem to be suggesting to somehow replace `object GetConfigAccessor` with `def getConfigAccessor` in the test code, but I am not aware of any mechanism, that would allow you to do that.

Comment: @Dima If you post that as a separate question I can explain it to you.

Comment: @Tim nah, I don't have a question here ... The OP did.